# Analysis of Vector process

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems, vector-analysis

I try to analyze the following vector process for some time now.

We have $n$ vectors $v_1(t), \dots, v_n(t)$ where $t$ indicates the current time step.
We consider discrete time steps.
Initially, all vectors have length $\leq 1$ and $> 0$.
Also, the vectors are connected initially.
Meaning that the endpoint of $v_1(t)$ is the starting point of $v_2(t)$ and so on.
The vectors at the next time step $t+1$ can be calculated as follows:

\begin{align*}
v_1(t+1) &= \frac{v_1(t)}{2\|v_1(t)\|} + \frac{1}{2}v_2(t)\\
v_i(t+1) &= \frac{1}{2}v_{i-1}(t) + \frac{1}{2}v_{i+1}(t) \\
v_n(t+1) &= \frac{1}{2}v_{n-1}(t) + \frac{v_n(t)}{2\|v_n(t)\|}\\
\end{align*}

It turns out that, if the vectors do not form a line initially,  this procedure converges and in the end all vectors are the same. However, I cannot predict the vector to which the vectors converge.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: What happens if $v_1(t)$ or $v_n(t)$ is $0$?  Or are you ignoring those cases?

Comment: I do not consider that case, thanks for mentioning! I edited the post.